# Integral involving logarithmics and powers: $ \int_{0}^{D} z \cdot (\sqrt{1+z^{a}})^{b} \cdot \ln(\sqrt{1+z^{a}})\; \mathrm dz $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, substitution

Do you guys have any ideas on solving the following integral:
$$ \int_{0}^{D} z \cdot (\sqrt{1+z^{a}})^{b} \cdot \ln(\sqrt{1+z^{a}})\; \mathrm dz $$ 
with $a, b$ being constants.

I was trying to use the formula (4.253.1) (shown below) of the book *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, 8th edition*, to solve the integral by applying change of random variable, but it seems not to work.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the antiderivative $$I=\int z \, (\sqrt{1+z^{a}})^{b} \, \ln(\sqrt{1+z^{a}})\, dz$$ let $$\sqrt{1+z^{a}}=t \implies z=\left(t^2-1\right)^{\frac{1}{a}}\implies dz=\frac{2 t \left(t^2-1\right)^{\frac{1}{a}-1}}{a}dt$$ which makes
$$I=\frac 2a \int \left(t^2-1\right)^{\frac{2}{a}-1} t^{b+1} \log (t)\,dt$$ and then
$$I=\frac{2 }{a \,(2+b)^2}\left(1-t^2\right)^{-2/a} \left(t^2-1\right)^{2/a} t^{b+2}\,J$$where $$J= \,
   _3F_2\left(1-\frac{2}{a},\frac{b}{2}+1,\frac{b}{2}+1;\frac{b}{2}+2,\frac{b}{2}+2
   ;t^2\right)-$$ $$(b+2) \log (t) \,
   _2F_1\left(1-\frac{2}{a},\frac{b}{2}+1;\frac{b}{2}+2;t^2\right)$$

where appear hypergeometric functions.

When $z\to 0$, $t \to 1$ and 
$$\lim_{t\to 1} \, I=-\frac{(-1)^{-2/a} \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{a}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{b}{2}+2\right) \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{b}{2}+1\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{b}{2}+\frac{2}{a}+1\right)\right)}{a (b+2) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{b}{2}+\frac{2}{a}+1\right)}$$

Comment: Hi, @Claude, thanks a lot for the answer, just to be sure, then the definite integral with interval from 0 to D can be solved by putting $t=\sqrt{1+D^a}$ into $I$ with hypergeometric functions and then minus $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 1} I$, right?

Comment: @Vic. You are correct. Cheers.

Comment: Great and thanks, @Claude, one more question, I did not follow the step on obtaining the hypergeometric function from the integral involving $t$, do you have any sources or references for that.

Comment: @Vic. Google for hypergeometric functions. This is an entire world. Have fun.

Comment: Hi, @Claude, yes, I know about hypergeometric functions, I was just curious about the reference on the equality $ \int \left(t^2-1\right)^{\frac{2}{a}-1} t^{b+1} \log (t)\,dt = \frac{1 }{(2+b)^2}\left(1-t^2\right)^{-2/a} \left(t^2-1\right)^{2/a} t^{b+2}\,\cdot \left[ 3F_2\left(1-\frac{2}{a},\frac{b}{2}+1,\frac{b}{2}+1;\frac{b}{2}+2,\frac{b}{2}+2
   ;t^2\right)- (b+2) \log (t) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{a-2}{a},\frac{b+2}{2};\frac{b+4}{2};t^2\right) \right]$, which seems quite complicated to me, and you must be very good at hypergeometric functions to find this equality somewhere. Thanks again.

Comment: @Vic. Don't think so ! It is every time a nightmare for me to work with these monsters. I saw your post on yesterday evening and decided to work the problem this morning. It has been quite tedious, be sure. I made a few  numerical checks and it seems to be OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71914/discussion-between-vic-and-claude-leibovici).